# Is crate log at its simplest using its own thread for output?

Tags: logging, rust, concurrency

Learning how you do logging in Rust.

```
env_logger::Builder::from_env(Env::default().default_filter_or("info"))
    .init();
info!("Logger initialised!");
```

With `log` and `env_logger`, are these messages logged "sync::mpsc::sync_channel" (multiple producer single consumer, preserving chronological order of submission), or not concurrent at all? [This](http://unhandledexpression.com:8081/general/2017/08/23/adventures-in-logging.html) seems to suggest not, and the author there appears to be trying to "roll his own".

If not, what's the simplest route to using a concurrent logger in Rust? Obviously, I could set up my own `sync_channel` arrangement. Just wondering whether there are any "turnkey" solutions to this.

Maybe it doesn't matter: maybe the pipeline is lightweight enough that log output from multiple threads will always be printed in chronological order? At the moment I'm only logging to console, but I will want to find out how to log to files, and I can imagine that might be trickier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing to understand is the [log](https://crates.io/crates/log) crate is simply a facade; it is just an interface between library crates that generate log messages and applications that direct and filter those messages however they prefer.

So the log crate does not coordinate threads at all. A logging implementation will be initialized into some global resource and the log macros will forward all calls to it. It is the logging *implementation* that dictates any concurrency, threading, or ordering properties.

In this case you're using the [env-logger](https://crates.io/crates/env_logger) implementation. It is pretty straight-forward and boils down to a write call to stdout directly where the log macro was called. No channel, or separate thread, or additional synchronization beyond that.

If you want different behavior so that the handling of logged messages doesn't slow down the code they are logged from, or your use-case is particularly sensitive to the timing and order, you'd have to use a different logging implementation that provides that kind of functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I spotted this: https://docs.rs/async-log/latest/async_log/ but people in this Reddit thread express some doubts about the approach taken there: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/c6wjbz/introducing_asynclog/. So nothing off-the-shelf by the look of it.

Comment: @mikerodent The async-log crate seems only targeted at *correlating* logs together when there's multiple things happening in your system at once. It doesn't seem to take any special care for the ordering itself. But as mentioned in others in the reddit thread, the [tracing](https://crates.io/crates/tracing) crate is a similar facade as the log crate but has this additional correlation built-in as well as `async`-support and other features. I much prefer it personally if that's what you're after.

Comment: Small nit: by default `env-logger` logs to `stderr`, not `stdout`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe take a look at [`spdlog-rs`](https://crates.io/crates/spdlog-rs) crate, it has an optional sink [`AsyncPoolSink`](https://docs.rs/spdlog-rs/0.3.12/spdlog/sink/struct.AsyncPoolSink.html) (with crate feature `multi-thread` enabled) that can log & flush records in a thread pool in parallel.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this crate.